# Adding controls in gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to add controls to a GridView dynamically, so I added a PlaceHolder, but it it giving me an error.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder plachldr = e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder2") as PlaceHolder;
    Button btn = new Button() { ID = "btnShhow", Text = "Show" };
    plachldr.Controls.Add(btn);

    PlaceHolder placeholder = e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
    TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
    placeholder.Controls.Add(txt1);
}
```

While adding the control to the PlaceHolder, is is giving me the following error:

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Here's the markup for my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">    
    <Columns>  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" />      
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>      
        <asp:TemplateField>  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>     
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>      
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You probably need to check for what type the row is - unless you have PlaceHolder2 in all the different row-types you can have within a GridView. So something like this: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) // your placeholder code here

Comment: @Pawan Bhise - is you issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

You need to check plachldr or placeholder  is null or not and also check for the `RowType`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if( if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
  {
    PlaceHolder plachldr = e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder2") as PlaceHolder;
    if(plachldr!=null)
    {
     Button btn = new Button() { ID = "btnShhow", Text = "Show" };
     plachldr.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    PlaceHolder placeholder = e.Row.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
    if(placeholder!=null)
    {
     TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
     placeholder.Controls.Add(txt1);
    }
   }

}
```

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

Comment: /ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

Comment: Use breakpoint in your binding method, and use quick watch, and go thru e.Row.Controls -- in order to see where is your placeholder, its ID. and how to get placeholder object.